# How do I set random effects of an lme model to zero or BLUP values?

Tags: mixed-model

According to Modern Applied Statistics, 4th Ed, page 276, it states
"Random effects are set either to zero or to their BLUP values."

My question is: how do i code that in my call to predict.lme?  I thought I'd need something in the newdata variable to do that but I understand that setting the effects to zero is not the same as removing the random term. I don't understand why not.  What should my newdata look like?

My formula:
bee.lme <- lme(Resp ~ Season *  Rate, random = ~ 1|Hive,
                          data = data_sel, na.action = "na.omit")

> version
>                  _
>   platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             linux-gnu
>   system         x86_64, linux-gnu
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          5.0
>   year           2018
>   month          04
>   day            23
>   svn rev        74626
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
>   nickname       Joy in Playing

Perhaps a better example is to use the model in the MASS book: pet5.lme <- lme(Y ~SG + VP + V10 + EP, random = ~ 1 + EP |No)

Comment: Perhaps a better example is to use the model in the MASS book:

Answer (score 2):

To control the type of predictions you obtain you need to use the `level` argument of `predict.lme()`. Namely, if you set `level` to 0 you get the predictions for which the random effects are set to zero. In the case of linear mixed models, these correspond to population predictions. If you set `level` to 1 in your case, you get group-specific predictions which condition on the BLUPs of the random effects.

Comment: To my understanding, level =  0 would be the same as omitting the random term, but I've been informed that is not so.  Why is it different?

Comment: In the case of linear mixed models, and because you have the identity link function, the predictions you get by settling `level = 0` are population predictions. However, if you have a generalized linear mixed model for a categorical response variable, and because there you need a nonlinear link function, the predictions calculated omitting the random effects are not population predictions.

Comment: Are population predictions what are given by the default newdata term in the call to predict()?

Comment: The default is group-specific predictions, not population predictions.